# htaccess image redirect

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, png

I need to redirect image to make it look shorter

What I have

```
"http://site.com/images/screenshots/509cd93aad063.png"
```

What I need

```
"http://site.com/509cd93aad063.png" or even "http://site.com/509cd93aad063" if possible.
```

I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.png)$ images/screenshots/$1 [L] - No success =(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a wildcard `.*`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.png)$ images/screenshots/$1 [L]
```

Even better, you can exclude / from the wildcard:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*\.png)$ images/screenshots/$1 [L]
```

That way the rule applys only at the root path.

A Tip, you can debug Regular Expressions online: http://regexpal.com/